# Different auth dialogs depending on user

Tags: facebook

I have created a new application and configured an "App on Facebook". The auth dialog looks different depending on the user trying to access the app.

The issue seems to be with different settings for the different users, but what is the cause?
I want every user to be presented with the first dialog.

[image: Default auth dialog]

[image: Compact auth dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow's login with Facebook is now showing the second type also.  One issue I am seeing with this is that if you trigger a post to feed after getting the second dialog, the permissions are always set to "Me Only", no matter what is set in your app settings.

Facebook has a habit of testing out new changes across random users, so it may be that this is the explanation for some users seeing one dialog or the other.

In fact, half the people tested at my office received one dialog, and half the other.

This may be related:  http://allfacebook.com/separate-screens-mobile-app-permission-requests_b115132